# QueueUserAPC access violation on x86

Tags: multithreading, winapi, access-violation

I'm trying to use `QueueUserAPC` to run some function asyncronously on a specific thread. My code is working ok when compiled for x64, but when I compile and run for x86, I get an access violation.

At the end of my post is a minimal, complete example that shows what I am trying to do (cleanup of thread and events omitted for brevity).

On my machine, when I compile and run for "x64", I get the expected output:

> waiting...
>
> async function!
>
> waiting...
>
> async function!
>
> waiting...
>
> ConsoleApplication3.exe (process 17100) exited with code 0.

When I compile and run for "x86", I get:

> waiting...
>
> async function!

And then the access violation, here:

`if (WaitForSingleObjectEx(param, INFINITE, TRUE) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)`

> Exception thrown at 0x776227FB (ntdll.dll) in ConsoleApplication3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x36623194.

What am I doing wrong?

**Full example:**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

DWORD ThreadFunction(LPVOID param)
{
    while (true)
    {
        printf("waiting...\n");

        if (WaitForSingleObjectEx(param, INFINITE, TRUE) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
            break;
    }

    ExitThread(0);
    return 0;
}

void AsyncFunction(UINT_PTR param)
{
    printf("async function!\n");
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE hThread, hStopEvent;
    DWORD threadID;

    hStopEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) ThreadFunction, hStopEvent, 0, &threadID);
    
    Sleep(1000);

    QueueUserAPC((PAPCFUNC) AsyncFunction, hThread, NULL);

    Sleep(1000);

    QueueUserAPC((PAPCFUNC) AsyncFunction, hThread, NULL);

    Sleep(1000);

    SetEvent(hStopEvent);

    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
}
```

Comment: `(PAPCFUNC) AsyncFunction` - the fact that you had to cast the function pointer should be a clue. `AsyncFunction` is not a valid PAPCFUNC but you forced the system to try (and it failed).

Comment: Thank you Raymond. Clearly spent too long staring at my screen today...

Comment: @TheNextman you are making the same mistake with `CreateThread()` and `ThreadFunction()`, too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two mistakes with my `AsyncFunction` definition:

1 - The parameter type should be `ULONG_PTR`, *not* `UINT_PTR`. This was actually a copy-paste error from my real implementation

2 - Missing calling convention from the function

`void AsyncFunction(UINT_PTR param)` should be `void CALLBACK AsyncFunction(ULONG_PTR param)`

And then there is no need for the cast to `PAPCFUNC` here:

`QueueUserAPC((PAPCFUNC) AsyncFunction, hThread, NULL);`

Comment: `ThreadFunction()` is also missing a required calling convention, and the typecast used in the call to `CreateThread()` is hiding that mistake. Get rid of the typecast and fix the signature: `DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunction(LPVOID param)`

Comment: first parameter actually pointer size value can be and `ULONG_PTR` and `UINT_PTR` and `PVOID`, etc. but calling convetion `__cdecl` via `__stdcall` here critical and exactly this lead to bug when you use `__cdecl`

Comment: Thanks! The `ThreadFunction` mistake is actually a copy-paste error from my real project. Good to know about the pointer size, I thought that was probably the case but it's good to match the function definition from MSDN I guess...

Comment: crash because and only because `ret` vs `ret 4`. define `void __stdcall AsyncFunction(MyStruct* )` is ok